# Rcpp Eigen Map Error with MatrixXf

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp

Why does the following code not compile?

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
    int rows(const NumericMatrix& X) {
        using Eigen::MatrixXf;  
        typedef Eigen::Map<MatrixXf> MapMat;
        MapMat X1(as<MapMat>(X));
        return X1.rows();
}', depends = "RcppEigen")
```

It throws the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >::Map(Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::iterator, int&, int&)'
         OUT get() {return OUT(vec.begin(), d_nrow, d_ncol );}
```

The same code works fine when I used MatrixXd instead.

Thanks.

Comment: We do not support `float` on the interface to R as R only has `double`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NumericMatrix` uses type `double` (as opposed to `float`). Eigen does not support implicit type casting between matrices using different types. Your code appears to try and read the memory of a `double` `NumericMatrix` as a `float` Eigen matrix. Just use the `MatrixXd` type instead.