# How do I convert R data types into an Eigen::Matrix<double,dim,1> in this situation?

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp

Why is this reporting `error: no matching function for call to ‘as<Eigen::Matrix<double, 400, 1, 0, 400, 1> >(int)’` and `cannot convert ‘3’ (type ‘int’) to type ‘SEXP {aka SEXPREC*}’`? There appears to be a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114103/rcpp-eigen-map-error-with-matrixxf).

In a [previous question, I asked about registering plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778952/correctly-registering-a-plugin-to-use-eigen-via-rcpp) so that I could use a c++ template library from within `R`. Continuing on with that example, I still cannot get this small example to work. The plugin issue has been figured out, but now `Rcpp::as` won't allow me to convert numeric vectors and matrices from `R` into the appropriate c++ type.

```
library(Rcpp)
inc <- 
'template <size_t dim>
class SillyWrapper  
{
public:
  Eigen::Matrix<double,dim,1> m_vec;
  SillyWrapper(const Eigen::Matrix<int,dim,1>& vec) : m_vec(vec) {};
  void printData() { Rcpp::Rcout << m_vec(0); };
};'
src <- '
void foo(){
  const int dim = 400;
  SillyWrapper<dim> myThing(Rcpp::as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double,dim,1>>>(3));
  myThing.printData();
}'
f <- function(x){
  plug <- Rcpp.plugin.maker(include.before = "#include <Eigen/Dense>")
  settings <- plug()
  settings$env$PKG_CPPFLAGS = "-I/usr/include/eigen3"
  settings
}
Rcpp::registerPlugin(name = "Eigen3", plugin = f)
fun <- cppFunction(code = src, 
                   plugins = "Eigen3",
                   includes = inc)
```

A few other things:

- I am registering my own plugin instead of using RcppEigen for practice (perhaps it will help later when I need to use other header only libraries). I plan on relying on plugins because I have a lot of header files I need to include, and I don't want to `paste` them all together and assign the massive string to `inc` above.
- I cannot use `Eigen::MatrixXd` I need to size the matrices with the compiler.
- [@DirkEddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) mentioned something about `configure` logic. I tried searching that, but no luck.

Comment: You have to write your own if you don't want to use the `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` specializations provided by `RcppEigen` (I still don't understand why ...). See http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-extending.pdf and https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/.